# Will the software updater work properly with more than one software depository on the system?

Tags: updates, lubuntu, software-center

On my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop,I have used the default software depository and the Lubuntu software depository on the same machine.I got to wondering if the software updater is able to update software regardless of where it comes from.I was also wondering if having more than one depository will cause any conflicts.Sorry,my Linux-speak is still a little fuzzy,But somebody managed to figure out what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have more than one repository. The Standard Ubuntu Software Center is a simplified view of available packages. If you use Synaptic Package Manager, it will list more, but it might be a bit confusing for a new user.  As @Lubuntu Lover mentioned there is a link that explains this a bit more, but might be a bit much to absorb.

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu is just a light version of Ubuntu with a faster desktop. All the usual Ubuntu updates will work via the Software Updater and using the repositories selected in the settings there (under the **Updates** tab). I suggest that you select 'important' and 'recommended'. Also make sure that you select the first 3 options (Canonical, Community, Proprietary) under the **Ubuntu Software** tab to get all the core software regularly updated.

I'm guessing that the Lubuntu repository that you're referring to is actually the Lubuntu Software Centre in your menu - which just gives you the option to install more software, rather than update it.

You can read about repositories [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)